# How do I apply mesh analysis to this circuit?

Tags: nodal-analysis, mesh-analysis

I have applied the mesh analysis to this circuit using both clockwise and counterclockwise directions but I ended with different results.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Please let me know if there's anything I'm doing wrong.
Also, how can I correctly apply **node analysis** to this circuit?

Comment: If you change the sense of \$i_1\$, you're also changing the voltage produced by the dependent source, so the two cases are not equivalent. They would be if in addition to flipping the sense of the currents, you also change the sign on the dependent source.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks a lot. I now understand. How can I however analyse the circuit using nodal analysis. I'm thinking it might boil down to a supernode (a concept which I don't fully understand).

Comment: @Jovanny, if you want to ask about how to solve this with node analysis, you should open a new question, because that's a totally different question than what you asked in this post.

Comment: @ThePhoton Okay 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the sense of \$i_1\$, you're also changing the voltage produced by the dependent source, so the two cases are not equivalent. They would be if in addition to flipping the sense of the currents, you also change the sign on the dependent source.